# Not able to validate JSON Web Token with .NET – key too short

Tags: c#, .net, owin, sha256, jwt

I have used `JSONWebToken` npm module to generate a jwt:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var payload = {
    "iss": "https://secure.example.com/",
    "exp": 1410819380,
    "http://example.com/orgnum": "987987987",
    "http://example.com/user": "me@example.com"
};

var token = jwt.sign(payload, 'secret');

console.log(token);
```

This gives me the following output:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZS5leGFtcGxlLmNvbS8iLCJleHAiOjE0MTA4MTkzODAsImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9vcmdudW0iOiI5ODc5ODc5ODciLCJodHRwOi8vZXhhbXBsZS5jb20vdXNlciI6Im1lQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNDA4Mzk0Mjk2fQ.5X5LTg4wxDF2p49xtsRcG4S9Yk4qSfW1tMEU0AquBhc

Since I'm not specifying what algorithm I want, it uses SHA256.

Now, I try to verify this in c#. That didn't turn out easy...

I get an exception about the key size:

> IDX10603: The 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey' cannot have less than: '128' bits.
>   Parameternavn: key.KeySize
>   The actual size was 48.

I I try to extend the key, I get a new error when creating the symmetric key:

> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

I recon this has something to do with the way I'm telling the .net code about my key. Since the `SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider` constructor parameter is named `base64Key`, I have tryed to Base64Url-encode my key:

```
        var secret =  Base64UrlEncoder.Encode("secret");
        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {                
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            IssuerSigningTokens = new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret).SecurityTokens
        };
```

**So, what are I missing here?

Why can `jsonwebtoken` generate and validate jots with short keys while .net can not?

And why can't .net accept the keys I give it?**

Here's the complete .net code with a jot signed with a long key:

```
        var jwtToken =
            "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZS5leGFtcGxlLmNvbS8iLCJleHAiOjE0MTA4MTkzODAsImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9vcmdudW0iOiI5ODc5ODc5ODciLCJodHRwOi8vZXhhbXBsZS5jb20vdXNlciI6Im1lQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNDA4Mzk1NjY4fQ.ZceiiEO_Mn5_GZp5D_r68VTT33fbocn1BTTznD6u3cs";
        var secret = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode("super duper secret with some more on top");


        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                IssuerSigningTokens = new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider("issuer", secret).SecurityTokens
            };


        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler()
            {
                Configuration = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration()
                    {
                        CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None
                    }
            };

        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        var claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwtToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
        return claimsPrincipal.Claims;
```

**Updated:**

I'm only using Microsoft-stuff in this code.  I'm using the `Owin` packages `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt` version `2.1.0` with `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` version `4.0.0-RC2`.

There are multiple blog posts out there stating that you'll need to manually update the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` package.

Comment: [TokenValidationParameters Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters%28v=vs.114%29.aspx) provided by Microsoft do not have `ValidateAudience`  and `IssuerSigningTokens` members. Could you please specify what library you are trying to use for validation?

Comment: Sorry. I'm only using Microsoft stuff. Will specify in the question.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what API you are using, since the [official Microsoft one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters%28v=vs.114%29.aspx) does not contain the properties that you are using. My guess would be, you are using an outdated version.

I took the API from this [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/). And this is the code, that worked for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens;
using System.Text;

namespace SO25372035
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const string tokenString =  @"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZS5leGFtcGxlLmNvbS8iLCJleHAiOjE0MTA4MTkzODAsImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9vcmdudW0iOiI5ODc5ODc5ODciLCJodHRwOi8vZXhhbXBsZS5jb20vdXNlciI6Im1lQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNDA4NDE5NTQwfQ.jW9KChUTcgXMDp5CnTiXovtQZsN4X-M-V6_4rzu8Zk8";
            JwtSecurityToken tokenReceived = new JwtSecurityToken(tokenString);

            byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret");
            if (keyBytes.Length < 64 && tokenReceived.SignatureAlgorithm == "HS256")
            {
                Array.Resize(ref keyBytes, 64);
            }
            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                AudienceUriMode = AudienceUriMode.Never,
                SigningToken = new BinarySecretSecurityToken(keyBytes),
            };

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(tokenReceived, validationParameters);
            IEnumerable<Claim> a = claimsPrincipal.Claims;
            foreach (var claim in a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(claim);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that I had to resize the array containing the key so that key length passes the validation. [It appears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Implementation) that they key length for HMAC is always equal to the block size, and for SHA256 it's [512 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm). There is [MinimumSymmetricKeySizeInBits static property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.signatureproviderfactory.minimumsymmetrickeysizeinbits%28v=vs.114%29.aspx) that defines the minimum length of a SimmetricKey, but it appears it can't be set to be less than 128.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into the keylength-thing. 
As for the api, I think maybe it's you that have the outdated version.. :-)

Comment: what about X509CertificateValidationMode ? how to change it with this approach ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode` api from `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt` package to decode the signing key

Then I do following to validate token:

```
var principal = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(jwtheader,
                        new TokenValidationParameters()
                        {
                            RequireExpirationTime = true,
                            ValidAudience = audience,
                            ValidIssuer = issuer,
                            IssuerSigningKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(secret)
                        }, out token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct about the key not being less that 128 bits, since support is only for AES that is the minimum.

You can use your own SignatureProvider.

I also think you are using older bits. Have a look at the latest.
http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/

If you have any issues, let me know.