# Problem getting a security token when using Json Web Token in a web API

Tags: c#, api, jwt, authorization, token

I am unable to get a security token when providing the web API with the proper validations.

I have already made a working web API. I am now adding a j.w.t authorization to get into the data. I have run into an issue that after entering the proper URL route I'am getting an HTTP 500 error, where it is meant to show me the security token. I will provide the code below.

Setup.cs

```
namespace testsitegp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<ICostomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IOrderItemRepository, OrderItemRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ISalespersonRepository, SalespersonRepository>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            var connection = "Server=tcp:testsitegp.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=H_Plus_Sports;Persist Security Info=False;" +
                "User ID=-------;Password=---------;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";

            services.AddDbContext<H_Plus_SportsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "JwtBearer";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JwtBearer";
            })
            .AddJwtBearer("JwtBearer", jwtOptions =>
            {
                jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = TokenController.SIGNING_KEY,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
                };
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

TokenController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace testsitegp.Controllers
{
    public class TokenController : Controller
    {
        private const string SECRET_KEY = "GSATDEHFG";
        public static readonly SymmetricSecurityKey SIGNING_KEY = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SECRET_KEY));

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Token/{username}/{password}")]
        public IActionResult Get(string username, string password)
        {
            if (username == password)
                return new ObjectResult(GenerateToken(username));
            else
                return BadRequest();
        }

        private string GenerateToken(string username)
        {
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                claims: new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
                },
                notBefore: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).DateTime,
                expires: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60)).DateTime,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(SIGNING_KEY, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
}
```

[A pic of the error page after entering the right route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t71s.png)

[same page but with developer exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxinZ.png)

this is the error message

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: IDX10603: Decryption failed. Keys tried: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
Exceptions caught:
'[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
token: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'
Parameter name: KeySize
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor(SecurityKey key, string algorithm, bool willCreateSignatures)
```

and in the console

```
 HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
GET - http://testapi.com/api/Token/yo/yo
```

Comment: your code works on local? could you add app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); on your current environment?

Comment: I tried flipping the authentication and MVC and that didn't change anything @RyanWilson

Comment: @gpjs I notice you call `.AddMVC()` twice inside of `ConfigureServices`, also can you please add your error message to your post instead of a link.

Comment: @jotade i have added a new pic with the developer exception.

Comment: @RyanWilson your right i have deleted one of the .addMVC(), and added the error message to the post.

Comment: @RyanWilson thank you so much that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `SECRET_KEY` is too short and needs to be a minimum of 128 bits [Not able to validate JSON Web token with .net - key to short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372035/not-able-to-validate-json-web-token-with-net-key-to-short)